# How to search Github GraphQL users by Company

Tags: github, graphql

I want to find all users that have set their "Company" field in their Github Homepage to "Github".  I see it is a defined field in the Github Docs at https://developer.github.com/v4/object/user/.  However, I can't seem to search for it.

My current query on https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/ returns no results

`{
  search(query: "company:Github", type: USER, first: 100) {
    userCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on User {
          login
          name
          company
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

To search all users by the company, query on the organization. Currently, you are passing a key-value pair as a string to search for instead of value string. Try this query to get all list of employees who have set their company name `Github`.

```
{
  organization(login: "github") {
    email
    members(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        ... on User {
          company
          login
          name
          isEmployee
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See the results in the attached image:
[image]