# Is there way to sort search result of GithubAPI Users?

Tags: http, github, frontend

Get users by name and then sort received users by their popularity for example by their followers
`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=followers:followers:%3E2000&page=1&per_page=100`

Something like this but to receive also username as query param?

Answer (score 0):

A GraphQL query ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549428/6309), adding the followers field) would be a better fit. (instead of [getting followers one user at a time through REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806411/6309))

You can then [apply a sort order](https://github.community/t/graphql-sorting-search-results/14088) (most-followers).